# Django orm: order post queryset by greatest number of tags from search

Tags: django, django-models, tags, django-orm

I want to order posts by the greatest number of tags a post has

my models:

```
class post(models.Model):
   description = models.Charfield(max_length = 2000)

class tag(models.Model):
    t = models.Charfield(max_length = 100)

class tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(tag, ...)
    post = models.ForeignKey(post,...)
```

I know django's orm supports many to many fields I have other reasons for doing it this way.

When inputs a search, example: purple mountain flowers
I want to query for posts that have any of the tags and order the query by the posts with the most matching tags. I'm new to using aggregation in django and have no idea how to structure this. Any recommendations?

here's what I've tried so far which doesn't work if my db has more than one match:

```
qs = post.objects.annotate(num_of_tags = 
Count(Subquery(tags.objects.filter(post = OuterRef('pk'), 
tag__body__in = search_list).only('pk')))).filter(num_of_tags__gt 
= 0).order_by('num_of_tags')
```

when there's more than one instance in my db it returns this error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should follow some python/Django standards for naming. Model class should be Titleized (Post, Tag, PostTag) and singular
You can use the option `through` to define your own model for m2m:

```
class post(models.Model):
    description = models.Charfield(max_length = 2000)
    post_tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, through=tags)
```

After that you can make use of django m2m to let you query easier:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count
qs = post.objects.annotate(
    num_of_tags=Count('post_tags', filter=Q(post_tags__body__in=search_list)))
).filter(num_of_tags__gt=0).order_by('num_of_tags')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll start naming my models according to convention. But There are some reasons I'm using a middle table instead of django's many to many field.